# In modal logic what is the difference between M,w |= p and M | q, w |= p?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Where p designates some proposition, M designates a model and w designates a world. Sorry if this question is too basic, but I think it is so basic that none of the basic textbooks and articles which I have consulted give a clear explanation. I understand that the first formula expresses that p is true under model M, in world p. But what does the second formula express?

A different example is from epistemic logic. What is the difference between:
M, w |= ￢Kap  and   M|￢Kap, w |= ￢Kap

Answer (score 2):

In the context of dynamic epistemic logic, the binary operator 'M <sub>| φ</sub>' takes a model M and a formula φ and 'updates' M, by removing from M all the worlds where φ is false ([Holliday], Lecture 13, Slide 7; [van Benthem], Chapter 15, Definition 15.2.1):

> M <sub>| φ</sub> = {v ∈ |M| : M, v |= φ}.

In the context of dynamic epistemic logic, this represents the process of learning, and can be used to give explications of belief-revision and so on. Here are some references to the relevant literature:

---

van Benthem, J. (2010) [*Modal Logic for Open Minds*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157586598X), Stanford, CSLI Lecture Notes #199.
Holliday, W.H. (2012) [*Modal Reasoning*](http://philosophy.berkeley.edu/people/page/123), Lecture Course (Spring), UC Berkeley.